# How to specify probabilities as a command line argument for my dna generator?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, dna-sequence

I wrote some code that can spit out a dna sequence of specified length, number of copies, specified probabilities, etc. In IDLE the program works fine as I preset the probabilities I want. I want this program to run efficiently from the command line.

How can I make my probabilities (weights) run as a command line argument like I've done for length and number of copies? I have no clue how to incorporate the probabilities as an argument in the command line. Thanks for your help!
    Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import random

weights=[.25,.25,.25,.25]
dna=['A','G','C','T']

def weighted_choice(weights,dna):
    totals = []
    running_total = 0

    for w in weights:
        running_total += w
        totals.append(running_total)

    rnd = random.random() * running_total
    for i, total in enumerate(totals):
        if rnd < total:
            return dna[i]

def dna_gen(length):

    seq=''

    for i in range(length):
        seq=seq+weighted_choice(weights,dna)
    return seq

def dna_gen2(reps,length,weights,dna):
    for i in range (reps):
        print (dna_gen(length))

def main():
    reps=int(sys.argv[1])
    length=int(sys.argv[2])
    weights=[float (w) for w in sys.argv[3:6]]
    dna_gen2(reps,length,weights,dna)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Specify them as percentages, in a single element, and split it: "25,25,25,25" --> [ 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 ]. Also, you could populate `totals` and `running_total` when you parse the command line, in order not to repeat the same calculation every time you call `weighted_choice`.

Comment: you should have a look at the `argparse` lib. It should do what you want. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import random

#weights=[.25,.25,.25,.25]
dna=['A','G','C','T']

def weighted_choice(weights,dna):
    totals = []
    running_total = 0

    for w in weights:
        running_total += w
        totals.append(running_total)

    rnd = random.random() * running_total
    for i, total in enumerate(totals):
        if rnd < total:
            return dna[i]

def dna_gen(length):
    seq=''
    for i in range(length):
        seq=seq+weighted_choice(weights,dna)
    return seq

def dna_gen2(reps,length,weights,dna):
    for i in range (reps):
        print (dna_gen(length))

if __name__=='__main__':
    reps    = int(sys.argv[1])
    length  = int(sys.argv[2])
    weights = [float (w) for w in sys.argv[3:6]]
    dna_gen2(reps,length,weights,dna)
```

Now when I try it on the command line:

```
python nameOfYourScript.py 2 2 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

I get:

```
CG
GA
```